# MySQL, make CASE() return one result only, the one matched

Tags: mysql, case

I have two tables:

```
agents(id)
agent_targets(agent_id, month, amount)
```

For each month I have a `month` field, so for example for the month June 2017 the field is `2017-05-01`.

Now, when I get all agents I also need to get their monthly targets, for the current month-year.

My query is as follow (simplified)

```
SELECT 
(CASE
    WHEN MONTH(targets.month) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(targets.month) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    THEN targets.amount
END) as monthly_target
FROM agent_targets targets
```

This returns what I expect, the problem is that is return multiple rows, of which all but one are `NULL` because it didn't match the `WHEN`, and one that return the amount I need.

But because I am doing this inside a bigger query when getting all agents, I only need the record that matched the `WHEN`, instead I always get a `NULL` result because it's the first row in the table.

Is there any way I can make the `CASE` 'stop' once the `WHEN` condition is met, and return only that result ?

Note that I cannot `GROUP BY` `agent_id` because there is already grouping in the original query.

Thank you

**EDIT/SOLVED**
Ok, so after a bit of trying I managed to make it work. Instead of using the `CASE()` I simply moved the whole condition in the `JOIN` statement, something like this

```
[...]
LEFT JOIN agent_targets targets ON agents.id = targets.agent_id AND MONTH(targets.month) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND YEAR(targets.month) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `WHERE` clause instead of `CASE`.

Comment: I cannot use WHERE because the original query is much more complex, but I managed to solve it by moving the condition in the JOIN statement

Comment: That is the same as using a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I was thinking about the 'normal' WHERE clause, not the one in the JOIN statement.